# How to yield a thread waiting for asynchronous operation?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, networking, boost-asio

Here's my network scenario: a server (implemented with boost asio) is receiving requests, process them, then pass to several hosts (using http client also implemented with asio), waiting for answers, process that answers, then replying to original request.

The problem is that hosts are granted with time limit, server must respect it while waiting for answers (i.e. if limit is 100ms, then server can't close connection before 100ms passed).

Since my server is using worker thread pool (each thread is running `boost::asio::io_service::run()`), in case of slow hosts blocking wait for answers becomes bottleneck very soon (i.e. all workers are busy waiting, no more requests can be served).

Here's server handler code (mostly skipped)

```
void connection::handle(asio::yield_context yield)
{
    // read request
    asio::async_read_until(socket_, request_buf, "\r\n", yield);

    // read headers
    asio::async_read_until(socket_, request_buf, "\r\n\r\n", yield);

    // handle request
    // THIS IS BLOCKING CALL
    request_handler_->handle_request(request_, reply_);

    // write reply
    asio::async_write(socket_, reply_.to_buffers(), yield[ec]);
}
```

And here's what handle_request does

```
http::client::client c(host, port);

// this is asynchronous call returning immediately
std::future<http::reply> res = c.send(request);

// BOTTLENECK PROBLEM HERE
// this is blocking wait for answer
auto reply = res->get();
```

First of all I can rewrite `handle_request()` in async manner like shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26728121 (that will not solve the problem, but can be useful furthermore). I can also pass callback to `client::send()` to avoid getting response explicitly.

I want somehow to "yield" that blocking wait until all responses are received, so workers will become free to serve other incoming requests in this period.

I tried `boost::coroutine` and `boost::fiber`, but w/o success, indeed these two just pass execution context, but I have no place to pass context, I just need to "wait".

Comment: The question is too broad. Short answer: no, you cannot "yield" that blocking wait. You can try to use std::async or thread worker pool to resolve this, but it depends.

Comment: @PSIAlt integrating back into the ASIO event loop either requires a hand-rolled event loop with manual polling or an ASIO extension that adds a reactor (likely with an extra service thread, so think of fork notifications)

Comment: By the way, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202398/is-there-any-way-to-asynchronously-wait-for-a-future-in-boost-asio - which might give you ideas

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to use a [`boost::asio::deadline_timer`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/deadline_timer.html) to do the waiting, up to the time limit, on the thread pool.

```cpp
boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(my_context);
timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(100));
timer.async_wait(yield);
```