# Boost ASIO: Asynchronous write, synchronously

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous, boost, boost-asio

I have a program (client + server) that works with no issue with this write:

```
boost::asio::write(this->socket_, boost::asio::buffer(message.substr(count,length_to_send)));
```

where `socket_` is `boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>` and `message` is an `std::string`.

I would like to make this better and non-blocking, so I created a function that could replace this, it's called like follows:

```
write_async_sync(socket_,message.substr(count,length_to_send));
```

The purpose of this function is:

1. To make the call async, intrinsically
2. To keep the interface unchanged

The function I implemented simply uses promise/future to simulate sync behavior, which I will modify later (after it works) to be cancellable:

```
std::size_t 
SSLClient::write_async_sync(boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>& socket, 
                            const std::string& message_to_send)
{
    boost::system::error_code write_error;
    std::promise<std::size_t> write_promise;
    auto write_future = write_promise.get_future();

    boost::asio::async_write(socket,
                             boost::asio::buffer(message_to_send), 
        [this,&write_promise,&write_error,&message_to_send]
        (const boost::system::error_code& error,
        std::size_t size_written)
        {
            logger.write("HANDLING WRITING");
            if(!error)
            {
                write_error = error;
                write_promise.set_value(size_written);
            }
            else
            {
                write_promise.set_exception(std::make_exception_ptr(std::runtime_error(error.message())));
            }
        });
    std::size_t size_written = write_future.get();
    return size_written;
}
```

The problem: I'm unable to get the async functionality to work. The sync one works fine, but async simply freezes and never enters the lambda part (the writing never happens). What am I doing wrong?

---

Edit: I realized that using `poll_one()` makes the function execute and it proceeds, but I don't understand it. This is how I'm calling `run()` for `io_service` (before starting the client):

```
io_service_work = std::make_shared<boost::asio::io_service::work>(io_service);
io_service_thread.reset(new std::thread([this](){io_service.run();}));
```

where basically these are `shared_ptr`. Is this wrong? Does this way necessitate using `poll_one()`?

Comment: Do you have a thread, calling the io_service.run() ?

Comment: @florgeng Oh, absolutely. The gear works all fine with a synchronous call to `write`. But asynchronous is the problem. `io_service` is passed to `socket_` on construction.

Comment: @florgeng Check my update :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Re. EDIT:

You have the `io_service::run()` correctly. This tells me you are blocking on the future inside a (completion) handler. That, obviously, prevents `run()` from progressing the event loop.

---

The question asked by @florgeng was NOT whether you have an `io_service` instance.

The question is whether you are calling `run()` (or `poll()`) on it suitably for async operations to proceed.

Besides, you can already use `future<>` builtin:

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/cpp2011/futures.html
- Example: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/futures/daytime_client.cpp

```
std::future<std::size_t> recv_length = socket.async_receive_from(
      boost::asio::buffer(recv_buf),
      sender_endpoint,
      boost::asio::use_future);
```

Comment: Oh, thanks for the future hint. That's beautiful! Although I'm calling run with `std::thread`, I found out that calling `poll_one()` will make it proceed. I don't understand why this happens. Please check my edit. I'd appreciate explaining whether there's an obvious reason for this.

Comment: Yeah it's obvious for the documented design of the proactor model: [ad. 5 at the bottom](http://think-async.com/Asio/boost_asio_1_10_6/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/basics.html); also [on threading](http://think-async.com/Asio/boost_asio_1_10_6/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html). The first async tutorial program spells _["Finally, we must call the io_service::run() member function on the io_service object."](http://think-async.com/Asio/boost_asio_1_10_6/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer2.html)_

Comment: Ah. Spotted the edit. Amended the answer. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202398/is-there-any-way-to-asynchronously-wait-for-a-future-in-boost-asio

Comment: I realized that the handler is being blocked by checking `std::this_thread::get_id()`. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Clarifying for any casual visitors from the future: Sam meant he spotted it by looking at the thread ids.  `this_thread::get_id()` doesn't block :)