# How to wait a std::future completion inside the boost.asio context?

Tags: c++, c++17, boost-asio

I want to have the pseudo code below working:

```cpp
void AddFutureToIoContext(std::future<int> f) {
    asio::io_context ctx;
    WaitForFutureAsync(ctx, f, [](const std::error_code& error){
        std::cout << "The future has come";
    });
    ctx.run();
}
```

What `WaitForFutureAsync()` should do to allow an external `std::future` object to be awaited inside the asio context guts? E.g. in same fashion as asio context waits for timer events.

C++ 17 is a limit.

Comment: relevant https://stackoverflow.com/a/18364281/85371

Comment: 10 years ago they expected a solution... soon...

Comment: You frame it as a problem. People have expectations, that's not the point. I too think it's a problem, but the problem is with API's using blocking futures instead of async patterns. Yes, I know, there has been a wave in programming history (not just C++) where this was the fashion. We learned and moved on. You can wrap your legacy API in an ASIO friendly wrapper and not deal with futures yourself. Maybe I'll find time to give that answer a modern update and post it

Comment: Looking at that answer it's not what I remembered. I will try to find what I thought I remembered instead. Meanwhile, here's how I'd write what they had in modern Asio: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2722e1b8a0350e69